# I'm new to react and I keep getting an undefined error, please can someone review my code?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I keep getting an "undefined" error in my react budget allocation app, please can someone help review my code?

So, I have been trying to add a dropdown currency menu to my budget allocation app. The webpage is meant to change to the corresponding option a user clicks. But each time I start the web page, I get an undefined error. Please can someone help me review my codeW

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import { AppProvider } from './context/AppContext';
import Budget from './components/Budget';
import ExpenseTotal from './components/ExpenseTotal';
import ExpenseList from './components/ExpenseList';
import AllocationForm from './components/AllocationForm';
import RemainingBudget from './components/Remaining';
import Currency from './components/Currency';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <AppProvider>
            <div className='container'>
                <h1 className='mt-3'>Company's Budget Allocation</h1>
                <div className='row mt-3'>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <Budget />
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <RemainingBudget />
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <ExpenseTotal />
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <Currency />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3 className='mt-3'>Allocation</h3>
                <div className='row '>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <ExpenseList />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3 className='mt-3'>Change allocation</h3>
                <div className='row mt-3'>
                    <div className='col-sm'>
                        <AllocationForm/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AppProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState,useContext,useEffect } from 'react';import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';

const Budget = () => {const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');const { dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
    changeCurrency()
  };

  const changeCurrency = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'CHG_CURRENCY',
        payload: currency,
    });
  }

useEffect(() => {console.log(currency);}, [currency] )

return (
    <div className="alert alert-secondary">
    <select id="inputGroupSelect02" onChange={handleChange}>
            <option defaultValue>Currency</option>
            <option value="$" name="dollar">$ Dollar</option>
            <option value="£" name="pound">£ Pound</option>
            <option value="€" name="euro">€ Euro</option>
            <option value="₹" name="ruppee">₹ Ruppee</option>
              </select>
              </div>
)};

export default Currency;
```

Comment: Usually errors show line and column numbers with them, can you share them please?

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting Currency, which is not defined (last line):

```
import React, { useState,useContext,useEffect } from 'react';import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';

const Budget = () => {const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');const { dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
    changeCurrency()
  };

  const changeCurrency = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'CHG_CURRENCY',
        payload: currency,
    });
  }

useEffect(() => {console.log(currency);}, [currency] )

return (
    <div className="alert alert-secondary">
    <select id="inputGroupSelect02" onChange={handleChange}>
            <option defaultValue>Currency</option>
            <option value="$" name="dollar">$ Dollar</option>
            <option value="£" name="pound">£ Pound</option>
            <option value="€" name="euro">€ Euro</option>
            <option value="₹" name="ruppee">₹ Ruppee</option>
              </select>
              </div>
)};

export default Currency; <<<<<<<< HERE
```

change it to

```
export default Budget;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but when I click on the currency, it doesn't reflect on the webpage. Please could you help me with that too, thank you.